# How can I make the audio of this mp4 downloaded with youtube-dl work?

Tags: sound, codecs, mp4, openshot

I opened the terminal of blender suite and typed:

```
youtube-dl -f22 youtubeaddress
```

The specifics of format 22 of the youtube-dl program is as follows:

> 22           mp4        1280x720   hd720 , avc1.64001F,  mp4a.40.2@192k (best)

I have no expertise in video-or audiocodes, I thought to recognize mp4 is sufficient.

I played the file with the parole movie player, I got video but no sound.
When I imported the file into the Openshot movie editor I also got video, but no sound.

I guess, the answer to my problem is somewhere in the format description:

> hd720 , avc1.64001F,  mp4a.40.2@192

I am clueless what this mean and how I can use this information to get the right audio codecs or something like this.

Comment: I read your link, but I am not sure if it is the same, for instance the best voted answer there suggests using -f22 this is what i ve done from the beginning.   I did not get it if it is a problem with youtube-dl or one with missing codes.

Comment: Can you play back the video with Totem or VLC? What's the output of `ffprobe <VIDEOFILE>` (any supported release but Trusty) or `avprobe <VIDEOFILE>` (Trusty)?